# Do I need to scan malicious files if they are in memory only?

Tags: python, security, file-upload, in-memory

I'm writing a Python tool that manages users' files across multiple providers like Google Drive, Dropbox, etc. It will allow uploading the files directly from the application memory to these providers with nothing stored at my own server. I also know that these providers have their own threat detection tools so the concern I have is regarding the safety of my own application.

So my question is, as soon as the user sends the file to my app when it loads the file into memory, if that file is a virus, can that be a threat being in memory? Am I opening a possible vulnerability and so should I scan the uploaded file? Again, nothing is ever stored on a hard drive.

Comment: Generally: if it's *just data*, there's nothing it can do. However, if you have some other vulnerabilities, and someone is able to load data into memory and then somehow cause your system to execute it through some unrelated vulnerability, well, that's a second order vulnerability. Of course, in order to scan the data, you need to load it into memory first as well…

Comment: Note that this is very little about Python, in such cases these questions can be better suited to other sites like [security.se]...